# linked list vs graph

Tags: c

I have two pieces of codes , one creates a linked list and the other one creates graphs and adds the edges in it.

A basic code for the linked list would be something like this

```
void create_list(node * current,int data){
    node *head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));
    head->data=data;
    head->next=NULL;
    current->next=head;

}

int main() {
    node *head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));
    create_list(head,4);

    node* temp=head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
      {
          cout<<temp->data;
          temp=temp->next;
      }
return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is 0.

Now, for a graph the basic code would be something like this

```
// A utility function that creates a graph of V vertices
struct Graph* createGraph(int V)
{
    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->V = V;

    // Create an array of adjacency lists.  Size of array will be V
    graph->array = (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList));

     // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by making head as NULL
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < V; ++i)
        graph->array[i].head = NULL;

    return graph;
}

// Adds an edge to an undirected graph
void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest)
{
    // Add an edge from src to dest.  A new node is added to the adjacency
    // list of src.  The node is added at the begining
    struct AdjListNode* newNode = newAdjListNode(dest);
    newNode->next = graph->array[src].head;
    graph->array[src].head = newNode;

    // Since graph is undirected, add an edge from dest to src also
    newNode = newAdjListNode(src);
    newNode->next = graph->array[dest].head;
    graph->array[dest].head = newNode;
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    // create the graph given in above fugure
    int V = 5;
    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V);
    addEdge(graph, 0, 1);
    addEdge(graph, 0, 4);
    addEdge(graph, 1, 2);
    addEdge(graph, 1, 3);
    addEdge(graph, 1, 4);
    addEdge(graph, 2, 3);
    addEdge(graph, 3, 4);

    // print the adjacency list representation of the above graph
    printGraph(graph);

    return 0;
}
```

I know the linked list returned zero because i need to pass the reference of the head pointer but what baffles my mind is that the same thing is happening in the graph code but the changes are visible globally, i.e. while adding an edge.

It might be a very naive question but help me comprehend the code?
Thanks!

Update:

```
void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest)
```

Here the graph is passed as a parameter to add edge and it still displays the changes globally but when i do the same with linked lists i.e.

```
void create_list(node * current,int data)
```

It doesnt displays the changes globally ,why?

Comment: `help me comprehend the code?` That's not a question. You should ask a specific question. What exactly don't you understand about the code?

Comment: let me update it @amit

Comment: Is this about c++ or c? Your code suggests the latter. I don't believe this question is relevant to both.

Comment: @Pandatyr made some changes to the question, yeah it is c.Pleasse review it again before downvoting it.

Comment: @amit you can check the question

Comment: `node *head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));` this part is totally broken

Comment: @milleniumbug as in ?

Comment: You're allocating the size of a *pointer to `node`*, not a `node`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `malloc` calls use `sizeof(node *)` instead of `sizeof(node)`.

Your `while` loop will display one too few and will display the [empty] `head` node (i.e. you get garbage instead of `4`).

Here's your code with annotations and fixes [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
void
create_list(node * current, int data)
{
// NOTE/BUG: malloc is incorrect
#if 0
    node *head = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node *));
#else
    node *head = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
#endif

    head->data = data;
    head->next = NULL;
    current->next = head;
}

int
main()
{
// NOTE/BUG: malloc is incorrect
#if 0
    node *head = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node *));
#else
    node *head = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: to ensure list is well formed, do this:
    head->next = NULL;

    create_list(head,4);

// NOTE/BUG: this doesn't work because it always displays one _less_ than the
// number in the list, so with one element in the list, it displays nothing
#if 0
    node *temp = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        cout << temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
#else
    node *temp = head->next;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}
```